# I cant´t add data to my database

Tags: php

Godd night. I have this code for php to add data to my database but i dont get succes.

```
 <?php
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$user = $_POST['User'];
$mail = $_POST['Mail'];
$token = $_POST['Token'];
$pass = $_POST['Pass'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 1 FROM Proteos where
        User='$user'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data==0){
    echo $data;
    echo "Hey, un grato saludo mister ".$user."!\n";
    $query = "INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ($user,$mail ) ";
}
mysqli_close($con)
```

And this is my config.inc

```
<?php 
define('DB_SERVER','mysql.smartfreehosting.net'); 
define('DB_NAME','u178665800_prote'); 
define('DB_USER','u178665800_carin'); 
define('DB_PASS','xxxxxx'); 
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS); 
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con); 
?>
```

Comment: put $user,$mail in single quote like '$user','$mail'

Comment: you does not execute your query $query. You just declare the query to variable

Comment: Was not usefull any of the suggestions

Comment: Btw do not mix mysql and mysql**i**

Comment: @jmattheis. You were right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String values have to be passed in quotes. Also execute the query . 
To debug use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ('{$user}','{$mail}' ) ";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
or
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

to connect with mysqli ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)) change in config.inc

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: i got this "Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'or die(mysqli_error())' at line 1".

Comment: added syntax for inserting with printing wrror. plz have a look

Comment: Solved. I change all my code with mysqli commands and it works.

Comment: @BrandonPrieto Happy to hear. Please accept the answer if helped

Answer (score 0):

Put your value in single quote And than execute query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ($user,$mail ) ";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ('$user','$mail') ";
```

And after that pass `$query` to `mysqli_query` like

```
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: i added with mysqli not mysql. did you changed your config.inc
with mysqli?

Comment: @BrandonPrieto you mixing up mysql and mysqli. so first check that and try again.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions. mysqli_* is prefered. i have edited my answer

Comment: @santhy it's okay.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php"); 


  if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $user = $_POST['User'];
    $mail = $_POST['Mail'];
    $token = $_POST['Token'];
    $pass = $_POST['Pass'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 1 FROM Proteos where
        User='$user'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data==0){
    echo $data;
    echo "Hey, un grato saludo mister ".$user."!\n";
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ('$user','$mail' ) ") or die(mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

check above code, values are insert using 'var' like `'$user','$mail'`
any error shows in the query helps to find the code  `or die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: I got this "Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'or die(mysqli_error())' at line 1".

Comment: Dear Brandon Prieto, I have updated the code , please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `VARCHAR (string)` data into Database without single quotes.

Data without single quotes is considered as either table/field names or integers or keywords.

Your entered data being none of these is causing errors.

Corrected SQL:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Proteos (User, Mail ) VALUES ('$user','$mail') ";
```